# onDraw() - Do I have to clear canvas first?

Tags: android

I have created a custom view to be shown in the action bar. It mostly works except sometimes on start I see a mirror copy of whatever I draw. The copy overlaps the original one but a few pixels away.

My `onDraw()` override is quite simple. All it does is draws an image that is centered in the canvas.

I am a bit confused. Am I expected to clear the canvas first in `onDraw()` method? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is confusing, but you'll notice in the custom view samples (that come with the sdk), the [`onDraw()` method](https://code.google.com/p/android-helloworld-samples/source/browse/trunk/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.java?spec=svn47&r=47#84) first calls `canvas.drawColor()` before anything else.

I assume it's not done automatically because it would be wasteful in the case where what you were drawing filled the entire view anyway. I just wish it was more clear that it is necessary in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out that others may find useful. If you set a background using setBackground(), the framework will actually draw the background before calling onDraw(). This background is drawn in the center. I too was drawing the background in onDraw() but I was drawing it from top-left. Hence, I was seeing the ghost image.

As Krylez mentioned, you may wish to call drawColor() as your first call in onDraw().

What I did was overrode setBackground() and its variations, and stored the background bitmap in a local variable.

Regards,
Peter